# How to add random value in Json Body in Gatling?

Tags: json, gatling

I need to create a random positive integer each time and send it to Json body in Gatling.

I used the below code to create a random positive ineger:

```
val  r = new scala.util.Random;
val OrderRef = r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

but, How can I feed the randomly generated value into the json body?

I tried:

```
.exec(http("OrderCreation")
.post("/abc/orders")
.body(StringBody("""{    "orderReference": "${OrderRef}"}""").asJson)
```

But, this doesn't seem to work. Any clues please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First of all you want to generate random number each time, thus `OrderRef` has to be a method, like:

```
def orderRef() = Random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

Side comment: by Scala convention: name camelCase, () while it generates new values, without `;` in the end.

To use the prepared method you cannot use the *Gatling EL string*. Syntax is very limited and basically `"${OrderRef}"` searches for variable with name `OrderRef` in Gatling Session.

Correct way is to use *Expression function* as:

```
.exec(
   http("OrderCreation")
  .post("/abc/orders")
  .body(StringBody(session => s"""{ "orderReference": "${orderRef()}" }""")).asJSON
)
```

Here you are creating anonymous function taking Gatling `Session` and returning `String` as body. String is composed via standard Scala string interpolation mechanism and uses before prepared function `orderRef()`.

Of course you can omit Scala string interpolation as:

```
.body(StringBody(session => "{ \"orderReference\": " + orderRef() +" }" )).asJSON
```

which is not very preferred style when using Scala.

See more details at Gatling documentation to [Request Body](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/http/http_request.html#request-body) and read more about [Galting EL syntax](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/expression_el.html).

An alternative way is to define a Feeder:

```
// Define an infinite feeder which calculates random numbers 
val orderRefs = Iterator.continually(
  // Random number will be accessible in session under variable "OrderRef"
  Map("OrderRef" -> Random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
)

val scn = scenario("RandomJsonBody")
  .feed(orderRefs) // attaching feeder to session
  .exec(
     http("OrderCreation")
    .post("/abc/orders")
    // Accessing variable "OrderRef" from session
    .body(StringBody("""{ "orderReference": "${OrderRef}" }""")).asJSON
  )
```

Here the situation is different, first we define the feeder, then we attach it to session and then use its value in request body via *Gatling EL string*. This works while the feeder value is taken from feeder by Gatling before an attached to session for each virtual user. See more about feeders [here](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/feeder.html).

Recommendation: If you scenario is simple, start with first solution. If it takes more complex think about feeders.

Enjoy

Comment: The first "correct" way to do it didn't work for me. The alternative way did work. Thanks.

Comment: Neither option worked for me. @Teliatko what version of gatling are you using?

Comment: Scratch that, the first option actually works for me, but the 2nd option does not.

Comment: @VivekRao At the time I was using Gatling 2.2. What is your version? I'd like to update the answer for new version there was a change.

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class PostRq extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol = http.baseUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
    .contentTypeHeader("application/json")

  val csvFeeder = csv("user-files/simulations/your_path/your.csv").random

  val scn = scenario("Request")
    .feed(csvFeeder)
    .exec(
      http("Request endpoint with dynamic payload")
        .post("/your_endpoint")
        .body(ElFileBody("user-files/simulations/your_path/template.json"))
    )

    setUp(
    scn.inject(
      constantUsersPerSec(5) during (1 seconds),
      nothingFor(4 second),
      constantUsersPerSec(10) during (1 seconds),
      nothingFor(4 second)
    )
  ).protocols(httpProtocol)

}
```

In the JSON template variables defined like

> "key_1":"#{my_var_1}", "key_2":"#{my_var_2}"

.
In the CSV dataset column names have to match the variable names.

```
my_var_1,my_var_2
value,value
value,value
...
```