# How to pass a variable to .get method in Gatling script

Tags: scala, gatling

How to pass a variable to .get method in Gatling script.
Here i am having Json file and need to pass a variable dynamically.
My Json Value is

```
[{ "id" = "Test1"}, {"id" = "Test2"}
```

Here is my gatling Script

```
 .feed(jsonFile("gabdeviceid.json").circular)
            .during(10 minute) {
             exec(http("request_0")
                    .get("/user/isTokenValid?id=${id}")
                    .headers(headers_0))
            }
```

Error: getting 405

but replace ${id} with Test1 it's working fine.

anywhere i done mistake can any one help me please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834933/how-to-dynamically-generate-json-in-gatling

Answer (score 1):

Change the formatting of your string:

```
.get("/user/isTokenValid?id=%s").format("${id}")
```

Whole script:

```
.feed(jsonFile("gabdeviceid.json").circular)
            .during(10 minute) {
             exec(http("request_0")
                    .get("/user/isTokenValid?id=%s").format("${id}")
                    .headers(headers_0))
            }
```